# X is used uninitialized in this function

Tags: c++, warnings

Why am i getting this warning?:
warning: 'row1[3]' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
I've been googling this for some time but but i can't find any answers, probably just because i'm inept at searching answers on Google.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int setfunc(int x);

int main()
{
    int row1[3]{0,0,0};
    setfunc(row1[3]);
}

int setfunc(int x[])
{
    string sub;
    int rowset;
    stringstream rs;
    string snums;
    int elementnum = sizeof(x) / sizeof(0);
    for(int z = 1; z <= elementnum; z++)
    {
        int find = snums.find(",");
        if(find == -1)break;
        else
        {
        sub = snums.substr(0, snums.find(","));
        rs << sub;
        rs >> rowset;
        snums.erase(0, snums.find(",") +1);
        }
        x[z] = rowset;
        cout << x[z] << endl;
    }
return 0;
```

}

All help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour of `int row1[3]{0,0,0}; setfunc(row1[3]);` is *undefined*. This is because the indexing runs from 0 to 2, so `row1[3]` is accessing the array outside its bounds. The compiler is helping you here, although in my opinion, the warning is a little misleading.

`sizeof(x) / sizeof(0);` is also incorrect. `sizeof(0)` is the size of an `int` since `0` is an `int` type. The normal idiom is `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`. But you **can't** do this either in your case since the function parameter `x` will have *decayed* into a pointer. You ought to pass the number of elements into the function explicitly.

Comment: in this case with the sizeof targeting a passed in array, won't it return the size of a pointer?

Comment: Yup you're correct. The size information is lost when passing to a function.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)